# How long does the Android browser keep its history files for?

Tags: browser

I'm one of those people who actually likes to keep all my old history files, since I like to see what sites I was browsing 6 months ago.

So does anyone know how long the Android browser stores data for? Or is there a maximum file size of the history file that it collects? Are there also any Android history archival utilities available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge-- all Android stock browsers will keep the history forever. 
Until the cache is manually wiped or wiped because of an OTA update -- since I'm pretty sure the updates wipe the cache before booting-- Even still, I'm pretty sure the browser's cache isn't touched in that process.

I'm quite certain you have nothing to worry about in terms of losing history.

If you are running 4.0.x (I think it's exclusive to that version- you could check), you can get the Chrome Beta browser, which keeps your history in sync with your Google account-- along with your bookmarks, and of course the history from any other machines you run Chrome on.

Pretty neat.

Comment: Can't verify it pre-ICS but my history only goes back for a week. I even checked the database there's nothing older than a week in there.

Comment: History is not cache it's data. And the /cache partition is another thing entirely.